# Generating Agora Token for my Flutter Live Stream App

Tags: node.js, flutter, postman, access-token, agora.io

So, am trying to generate a token for my audio live stream flutter app, following this tutorial article [here](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/agora-express-token-server/).

Go to this point to request endpoint to get Rtc token: [image]  Then I got stuck here with this error[image] [image]
I want  to add a POST handler to generate RTC authentication tokens using the buildTokenWithUid method. This is my first of using Postman

Comment: Choose `raw json` in postman, not `raw text` https://prnt.sc/1trihza

Comment: Tried it, still getting the same error: Agora not defined.. I think am missing something but I don't know what it is..

Comment: find the var `Agora` in nodejs code, this var hasn't been delared but was used somewhere.

Comment: The var Agora was the problem.. I didn't define it. Thanks 